# Hide SparkSession builder output in jupyter lab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I start pyspark `SparkSessions` in Jupyter Lab like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import findspark
findspark.init(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'])

spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .appName('myapp')
    .master('yarn')
    .config("spark.port.maxRetries", "1000")
    .config('spark.executor.cores', "2")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
    #...
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

And then a lot appears in the cell output...

> WARNING: User-defined SPARK_HOME (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p3969.3554875/lib/spark) overrides detected (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark).
> WARNING: Running spark-class from user-defined location.
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hadooplog/sparktmp
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hadooplog/sparktmp

> ...

I would like to hide this output to clean up notebooks and make them easier to read. I've tried `%%capture` and `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")` (although this only pertains to spark session logging, but even then, output still appears here and there). None of these work.

Running

- pyspark version 2.4.0
- jupyterlab version 3.2.1